# python: repeating elements in a list based a predicateHow

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I'd like to repeat elements of a list based on a predicate.
I tried using the module itertools and a list comprehension

```
abc = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = [ repeat(item,2) if item==3 or item==7 else item for item in abc ]
```

This doesn't fail at runtime, but the resulting object is not 'flattened'
If I print it, I see

```
[1, 2, repeat(3, 2), 4, 5, 6, repeat(7, 2), 8, 9]
```

Is it doable with a list comprehension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
from itertools import repeat
abc = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = [x for y in (repeat(item,2) if item==3 or item==7 else [item] for item in abc) 
          for x in y]

>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]
```

The trick here is to put `item` in its own list `[item]` and than flatten the now consistently nested list.

to improve readability, put it in two lines:

```
nested_items = (repeat(item,2) if item==3 or item==7 else [item] for item in abc)
result = [item for nested_item in nested_items for item in nested_item]
```

Since `nested_items` is an iterator, there is no extra list created her.